# Why does my QGIS WMS Server work only when Ignore GetMap/GetTile and GeoFeature Info are checked?

Tags: qgis, geoserver, authentication

I am creating an API that runs between QGIS and my GeoServer that includes Basic Authentication which is read by the API that confirms if that user has an account with us. I can load the majority of the layers when:

- Ignore GetMap/GetTile URI reported in capabilities
- Ignore GetFeatureInfo URI reported in capabilities

are both checked.

When they are not both checked, the layer doesn't load and I get a pop-up asking for the GeoServer realm credentials.

I can load layers from the GeoServer from OpenLayers just fine which uses Basic Authentication. So I feel that the problem lies within QGIS.

What part of the QGIS authentication may be the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 2):

QGIS processes the `getCapabilities` response from the server to work out what requests to make for `getMap` and `getTile` requests. If you have not set the [proxy](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/configuration/globalsettings.html) in the global settings page then your `getCapabilities` document is likely still pointing to `localhost:8080` and so QGIS will be unable to connect to it using this address.

By checking the ignore capabilities button, you admit this to QGIS and it uses the address of the `getCapabilities` document to work out of the address of the server.

Comment: Thank you so much Ian! Working on setting up the proxy now